# export highcharts funnel something went wrong while converting

Tags: highcharts, export

I want export a funnel highchart using JSON, I do with demo page (http://export.highcharts.com./demo) to export, but return error:

```
Oops..,  Something went wrong while converting.
```

I'm using JSON of example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/funnel/

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'funnel',
        marginRight: 100
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales funnel',
        x: -50
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                color: 'black',
                softConnector: true
            },
            neckWidth: '30%',
            neckHeight: '25%'

            //-- Other available options
            // height: pixels or percent
            // width: pixels or percent
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Unique users',
        data: [
            ['Website visits',   15654],
            ['Downloads',       4064],
            ['Requested price list', 1987],
            ['Invoice sent',    976],
            ['Finalized',    846]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: That jsFiddle works for me. Do you mean you are trying to export your own funnel chart? Are you using the export server provided by HigCharts or your own?

Comment: jsFiddle work right. When I copy json of jsFiddle and  I try to export using export server provided by HigCharts fail

Comment: Does the chart render correctly before you try and export? Did you include the export js file?

Comment: Yes, I copied settings of chart of jsFiddle demo and paste on export server demo, but fail

Comment: I am not sure what "paste on export server demo" involves.

Comment: I copied object of jsFiddle demo I write in field: Options
Specify here your Highcharts configuration object and then click button Generate Image

Comment: Yeah, looks like exporting demo page doesn't work with funnel (looks like funnel.js isn't included). I have reported it [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1995). Thanks!